# looping a function on a df list and save results in r

Tags: r, list, paste, lapply

I have different dataframes and what I want to do is:

1. apply a function repeated times to each dataframe
2. save results of each repetition on a new dataframe keeping the name of the original dataframes and adding something else to differentiate it

Here is what I have tried until now

```
 # read all files to list
 dataframes <- dir( pattern = ".txt") 
 list_dataframes <- llply(dataframes, read.csv, header = T, sep =" ", dec=".", na.string = "nd")  
 n <- length(dataframes)

 # apply myfunction 10 times
for (j in 1:10){
modified_list <- llply(list_dataframes, myfunction) 
}
if (j <10){
num.char <- paste("n0", j, sep="")
} else num.char <- paste("n", j, sep="")

# save back data frames
for (i in 1:n)
write.table(file = paste( "newfile/_modified",num.char, ".csv", sep = ""), 
modified_list[i], row.names = F)
```

What I want as a result is the modified dataframes (in this case the 10 repetitions for each df of the list)that will have:

- the name of the original df
- the new name
- and the number of iteration

  Something like`originaldfname_newname_n0`

I can not find where I'm missing up. Any help will be deeply appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two major issues, I think:

- the `}` (line 9 above) should be after your second `for` loop;
- your last line should probably reference `modified_list[[i]]` instead of using the single-`[` notation.

So your code should work (untested, slightly modified for style) as:

```
library(plyr)

# read all files to list
dataframes <- dir(pattern = ".txt") 
list_dataframes <- llply(dataframes, read.csv,
                         header = T, sep = " ", dec=".", na.string = "nd")  
n <- length(dataframes)

# apply myfunction 10 times
for (j in 1:10) {
  modified_list <- llply(list_dataframes, myfunction) 
  # save back data frames
  for (i in 1:n)
    write.table(file = sprintf("newfile/%s_newname_%02d.csv", dataframes[i], j), 
                modified_list[[i]], row.names = FALSE)
}
```

If this were code golf, the last portion could be reduced a little with:

```
for (j in 1:10) {
  mapply(function(df, nm) write.csv(file = sprintf('newfile/%s_newname_%02d.csv', nm, j),
                                    df, row.names = FALSE),
         llply(list_dataframes, myfunction), dataframes)
}
```

(This doesn't necessarily make it perfectly clearer, but it does reduce things a bit. Use it if you at some point prefer to not use `for` loops, though the performance in this case will be almost identical.)

Note:

- Please include required libraries, e.g., `library(plyr)`.
- Though `lapply` would have worked just fine, I kept the use of `llply` to match your example.